# Accumulation Points of a Set

Tags: general-topology

I've recently been studying accumulation points as part of a class and I'm slowly beginning to understand them I think.

I've been working on finding the accumulation points for the set

$( j + (1/k))$ such that j,k $\in$ N \ {1}.

I believe that after working this out the accumulation points are the set all real numbers minus all integers. i.e. R \ N

This is because the sequence is always approaching the integers, but does not ever include them in the set. Am I correct?

Comment: The exact opposite.  Because the sequence is "always approaching" the integers, the integers *are* the accumulation points.   R/N are not.  Every neighborhood of an integer contains an infinite many points int the set so every integer *is* and accumulation point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No: the accumulation points *are* the integers $j \in \mathbb{N} \setminus \{1\}$. Every open set containing $j$ contains a point $j + (1/k)$, which is unequal to $j$ (the open set contains infinitely many such points, in fact, all unequal to $j$). Thus, by definition, $j$ is an accumulation point of $S_j = \{j + (1/k) \mid 2 \le k \in \mathbb{N} \}$, so it's an accumulation point of your set $\bigcup_{j \in \mathbb{N} \setminus \{1\}} S_j$.